# How can i make a variable recive both a string and a int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code, but it does not work with python 3.4

```
print ("Hello")

b = str(input("Where do you go?\n"))

def place(a):
    if a == "r" or a > 0:
        print("Turned right.")
    elif a == "l" or a < 0:
        print("Turned left.")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        a = int(str(input("Where do you go?\n")))
        place(a)

place(b)
```

I want to make 'b' to be either an int or a string

Comment: What are your reasons for doing this?

Comment: `I want to make 'b' to be either an int or a string` I don't know what this means. Python is dynamically typed, so depending on what you mean, Python behaves this way already.

Comment: @MikeBell I tryied just using b = input, but it does not even compile. I am using IDLE 3.4.0

Comment: ? The line of code `b = input("Where do you go?\n")` runs just fine.

Comment: @MikeBell it should work. If I use a 'r' or 'l' it works, but using a number i get this error                                                   >>> 
Hello
Where do you go?
r
Turned right.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Hello
Where do you go?
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\J\Desktop\dsada.py", line 15, in <module>
    place(b)
  File "C:\Users\J\Desktop\dsada.py", line 6, in place
    if a == "r" or a > 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Comment: Well that's not a compile-time error, and it's not erroring on the `input` line. It sounds like IanAuld's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: As a side note, there's no reason to do `str(input(…))`, because `input` is already guaranteed to return a `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this not what you're going for?

```
def place(a):
    try:
        b = int(a)
    except ValueError:
        b = 0

    if (b != 0):
        if b > 0:
            print("Turned right.")
        else:
            print("Turned left.")
    elif (type(a) is str) and ((a == 'r') | (a == 'l')):
        if a == 'r':
            print("Turned right.")
        else:
            print("Turned Left")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        raise TypeError("Nothing to do")
```

Comment: your code worked with str character, but if b = 1, it goes to invalid

Comment: Yes, I am using IDLE SHELL, could be it?

Comment: This new code seems to work for both integers, strings and integers as strings.

Comment: @JoãoVictorMartinelli Can you mark my solution as the `Answer` so I can get some points please?

Comment: `type(a) is str` is better written as `isinstance(a, str)`. But really, why check it in the first place? Also, `TypeError` is a weird thing to raise for a user typing `f` instead of `r` or `l`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `try except` block:

```
b = input("Where do you go?\n")

def place(a):
    try:
        a = int(a)
        # code for a being a number
    except ValueError:
        # a is a letter
```

Comment: No need for `str(input(...))`. A string is returned by `input` already.

Answer (score 1):

The isdigit() method will tell you if a string is an integer.

```
a = "1"
if a.isdigit():
    a = int(a)
```